# How to seperate user input word delimiter as space using strtok

Tags: c, strtok

Why am I getting a segmentation fault after only reading one word?

If I enter "why is this not work"

I only get back

why

and then I get a segmentation fault.

I've seen other examples but none have used user input like I am trying to do here. I can only read one word and it won't work. I tried changing all the %c to %s but it is not helping me. I also realize segmentation fault is pointer pointing to somewhere not in memory but I cannot see what is wrong with it. Please help me understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char word[100];

    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    scanf("%s", word);

    char *tok = strtok(word, " ");
    printf("%s\n", tok);

    while(tok != NULL)
    {
        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
        printf("%s\n", tok);

        if(tok == NULL)
            printf("finished\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I changed scanf("%s", word); to fgets(word, 100, stdin); and now it prints everything but I get a Segmentation fault.

Comment: `scanf("%s", word);` does not save spaces in `word`, only `"why"`.  Use `fgets()`.

Comment: @chux thanks dude I changed it to fgets(word, 100, stdin) but I still get segmentation fault.

Comment: Hint: Why does code do `printf("%s\n", tok);` and _then_ check for `if(tok == NULL)...`?

Comment: Change to`char *tok = strtok(word, " \n");
    while(tok != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }   printf("finished\n");`

Comment: I highly recommend trying out a debugger whenever you get a segmentation fault. Usually in this case there is a `NULL` pointer somewhere you didn't expect, and the debugger will let you find it fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed in comments, there is at least two problems in your first code.

1. Do not use `scanf` to read a string that you want to parse. Use `fgets` instead.
2. You do not test that `tok` is not NULL before using it (inside the `while` loop)

Such problems would have been easily detected with debugging, so I encourage you to read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Corrected code should be like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char word[100];

    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    /* read from stdin 
       note the `sizeof char`, if you need to change the size of `word`,
       you won't have to change this line. */
    fgets(word, sizeof word, stdin);

    /* initialize parser */
    char *tok = strtok(word, " ");

    while (tok != NULL)
    {
        /* printf token: it cannot be NULL here */
        printf("%s\n", tok);

        /* get next token*/
        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    printf("finished\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggest declaring `char *delim = " \n";` and then `char *tok = strtok(word, delim);` (with like changes using `delim` throughout).

Answer (score 0):

This code is not correct

```
while(tok != NULL)
{
    tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
    printf("%s\n", tok);

    if(tok == NULL)
        printf("finished\n");
}
```

suppose you get to the last pass through the loop.... it gets into the loop as you got last time.... so you make a `tok = strtok(NULL, " ");` which returns (and assigns) `NULL`  as there is no more stuff.... then you `printf(3)` it, which produced the seg fault.

Just change that into this, so you don't enter into the loop if no more tokens are available.

```
while((tok = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", tok);

    /* you don't touch tok inside the loop, so you don't need to
     * test it again once you get inside */
}

/* if(tok == NULL)  <-- you always have tok == NULL here */
printf("finished\n");
```

or simpler

```
while(tok = strtok(NULL, " "))
{
    printf("%s\n", tok);
}
printf("finished\n");
```

Also, add `\n` to the second parameter of `strtok(3)` call (in the two calls you have in your listing, as you can have only one token, and the final line ending has to be dropped from the first call), as when you use `fgets(3)` you normally will get a `\n` at the end of the string (which you don't want):

```
char *tok = strtok(word, " \n");
printf("%s\n", tok);

while(tok = strtok(NULL, " \n"))
{
    printf("%s\n", tok);
}
printf("finished\n");
```